# Using forEach with single document queries in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How should I write a query for Firestore when I know that the number of document references returned will be only 1?

```
const query = firebase.firestore().collection('Users').where('mobile', '==', '<some mobile number>').limit(1);
```

To get the document from this query, I'm using the `forEach` loop. Is there any way to get the document and its data without using the loop?

```
let docId;

query.get().then((snapShot) => {
    snapShot.forEach((doc) => {
        docId = doc.id;
    });
    if(docId) {
        // doc exists
        // do something with the data...
    }
}).catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Comment: Can't you handle the data inside the `forEach` loop? Is `snapShot` an array at that time?

Comment: @Icepickle. That's what I'm not sure of. Even if the thing I query is unique, I have to use the forEach loop which I don't want to for a single document reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK. I figured it out.

The `.docs()` method can be used on the `snapShot` object to get an array of all the documents refs matching the query.

So, if I only have a single document, I can simply access it as follows:

```
query.get().then((snapShot) => {

    const doc = snapShot.docs[0];

    const docId = doc.id;
    const docData = doc.data();
    // so stuff here...

}).catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```